# Unable to encode Flex Grid data into JSON on sorting columns

Tags: json, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

Created an editable flex grid which exposes a method called getGridData() to javascript. I am using the JSON.encode() method of the com.adobe.serialization.json library to convert the grid object's dataProvider into JSON before returning it.

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("getGridData", getGridData);

public function getGridData():String
            {
                var ac:ArrayCollection = grid.dataProvider as ArrayCollection;  
                var jsonData:String = JSON.encode(ac); //failing here
                return jsonData;
            }
```

However, when I sort a column in the user interface, the encode method is failing throwing the following error

```
Property usingCustomCompareFunction not found on mx.collections.SortField and there is no default value.
```

Unable to figure out wht is going wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Encode the source of the dataProvider

```
public function getGridData():String {
    var ac:ArrayCollection = grid.dataProvider as ArrayCollection;  
    var jsonData:String = JSON.encode(ac.source); //failing here
    return jsonData;
}
```